# RStudio: Section numbers not knitting but will via command line

Tags: r, yaml, rstudio, r-markdown

have a RMarkdown document that I can convert at the command line with Pandoc and the --number-sections switch. The section numbers render 100% in the converted HTML.

However, I want to knit in the R chunks.
When I try and do a Knit to HTML in RStudio on the same file with the YAML header:

[image]

the sections numbers are not rendered. What am I doing wrong with the YAML?

Selecting the Knit with parameters option also says there are no parameters, should it not read the YAML header and see them?

Comment: Should be an underscore, i.e. `number_sections: TRUE`. (; See https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html

Comment: Yes!!! What a stupid mistake, please convert your comment to an answer. Knit with parameters must work separate to the YAML as still does not see

Comment: I have stopped counting my stupid mistakes. (;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be an underscore, i.e. `number_sections: TRUE`. (;

See https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html